# print out value from Apache access log

Tags: javascript, php, json, apache

Ive the following senario .

user will access www.myhomepage.com/cdn

Ive configured  custom  header value when user servicing from CDN  and its print cdn name into apache access.log  as CDNProvider

```
httpd.conf:LogFormat "%h %l %u %t %D \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" \"%{True-Client-IP}i\" \"%{CDNProvider}i\"" combined



4.26.226.141 - - [07/Dec/2014:16:13:47 +0400] 2346 "GET /web/ajax/alert/ticker.json HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "websitehere" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36" "-" "Level3"
```

When i check access the home page its print out my cnd provider name its dynatmic value as i user 2 cdns both provider custom header value

Now my question what is the best approve to print/grap the value from access log or parse it from the header when request www.myhome.com/cdn

and print the value into that page  www.myhome.com/cdn

Comment: Is the page already dynamic?

Comment: no static / if its require i can make it dynamic